# A space is added in on the second line of my output. Cant figure out how to remove it

Tags: c++, space

When I output the code on the second line of output there is a space added in that I cannot figure out how to remove. I have searched on this site and google for an answer. Sorry this is a simple fix. Would post a picture but dont have enough reputation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>


using namespace std;

// global constant variables
const int YEARS = 8;
const int MONTHS = 12;
const int SPACER =5;

// function prototypes

// function to read in values
void getData(double[][MONTHS], int[]);
// function to display values in table format
void printData(double[][MONTHS], int[]);


// function to print data to screen in table format using arrays

int main()
{
    double rain [YEARS][MONTHS];
    int years[YEARS];
    /*cout << " ";*/
    getData(rain, years);
    printData(rain, years);

return 0;
}


// function definitions 

void getData (double rainArray[][MONTHS], int yearArray[])
{
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("rainfall.txt");

    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file, shutting down now.\n" ;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++)
        {

            fin >> yearArray[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < MONTHS; j++)
            {
                cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
                fin >> rainArray[i][j];

            }
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}   

void printData (double rainArray[][MONTHS], int yearArray[])
{

    for ( int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++){
        cout << yearArray[i] << setw(SPACER);
        for ( int j = 0; j < MONTHS; j ++)
            {cout << rainArray[i][j] << setw(SPACER);
            if (j == 11)
                cout << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the output in plain text, not a picture.

Comment: Are you sure the input file has enough data?

Comment: You don't call `setw(SPACER)` before printing the first column of the first line. But you call it after printing the last column of the line, so the first column of the second line has this width.

Comment: Why are you writing `fixed` and `setprecision(1)` every time through the input loop? Just do that once at the beginning of `printData()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `setw()` calls (as with all stream manipulators) need to be *before* the item whose printing they're meant to affect.

```
cout << setw(SPACER) << yearArray[i];
```

You were placing them after the items, so they took effect on all lines except the first (giving the results described in the question).

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `setw()` *before* the field it applies to, not after.

```
void printData (double rainArray[][MONTHS], int yearArray[])
{

    cout << fixed << setprecision(1);    
    for ( int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++){
        cout << setw(SPACER) << yearArray[i];
        for ( int j = 0; j < MONTHS; j ++)
            {cout << setw(SPACER) << rainArray[i][j];
        }
        count << endl;
    }

}
```